# QtCreator 5.0.0 - Set the background color of the area right to the editor margin

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have just installed QtCreator 5.0.0. for Windows.

Since I prefer a visible margin line after 100 columns I did the following:

In the `Options` menu under `Text Editor`/`Display` I've activated the checkbox `Text Wrapping`/`Display right margin at column` and set the value to `100`.

I actually expected only the thin vertical line like in older Versions of QtCreator. But now, unfortunately, the background color of the window to the right of the margin is gray as well. How can I turn this off again? I haven't found an option and it's also not customizable in the color scheme.

[image]

Comment: means that you want this but you want to change gray color to white?

Comment: In previous versions, only a thin vertical line was displayed, the background to the right of it had the editor background color again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since QtCreator 9.0.0 it is now possible to switch between a single line and a completely tinted area in the settings via the option 'Tint whole margin area' in the QtCreator settings.